# Read line by line using timer

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, timer, readfile

I am trying to read each line by specific interval using python timer from a txt file 
But it read first line only and it shows continuously

my code is

```
def read():
    try:
        while True:
            fo = open("foo.txt", "r")
            threading.Timer(1.0, read).start()
            line=fo.readline()
            print line
            if len(line)==0:
                break
    except:
        pass
read()
```

Comment: why you every time open file in while loop?

Comment: I tried open before while loop and it show same problem

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Well I have a text file which containing recorded data from serial port .And now I am trying to play back the data .I have successfully done the recording part and saved the data in txt file

Comment: Use simple code like `with open("lines.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line`. and add timer.

Comment: @Jayresh post it as an answer

Comment: Well I have a text file which containing recorded data from serial port .And now I am trying to play back the data .I have successfully done the recording part and saved the data in txt file using timer.Sleep method will work but I am doing a robotics application in arm ,So I need playback of data with specific rate thats why I am sticking on timer

Comment: @Jayesh I have tried your solution but it shows I/O Error : [error no:24]:too much opened file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you again open the file , which starts reading from the first line , and you read that line print it and again continue the loop, this makes the loop an infinite loop.

Also, what you are doing with `threading.Timer()` is not how you use it, `threading.Timer()` starts the function `read` in a new thread after 1 sec, after sometime you would have loads of threads all running the `read()` function indefinitely.

What you are trying to do can easily be accomplished (without using `threading.Timer()` ) by using `time.sleep()` , to make your program sleep for a specific amount of seconds. Example -

```
def read():
    import time
    with open("foo.txt", "r") as fo:
        for line in fo:
            print line
            time.sleep(1)
read()
```

---

If you really want to use `threading.Timer()` , then you do not need the `while` loop and you should pass the file object as an argument to the function, Example -

```
def read(fo):
    line=fo.readline()
    print line
    if len(line) == 0:
        return
    t = threading.Timer(1.0, read, args=(fo,))
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

And then call the function initially as  -

```
with open("foo.txt", "r") as fo:
    read(fo)
```

Example/Demo -

```
>>> def a(x):
...     if  x >50:
...             return
...     print(x)
...     t = threading.Timer(1.0 , a, args=(x+1,))
...     t.start()
...     t.join()
...
>>> import threading
>>> a(1)
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: Yeah it work fine but it is not reliable for robotics application like move arm with specific speed and rate that's why I am trying timer .Timer has specific and accurate rate

Comment: Well I have a text file which containing recorded data from serial port .And now I am trying to play back the data .I have successfully done the recording part and saved the data in txt file using timer.Sleep method will work but I am doing a robotics application in arm ,So I need playback of data with specific rate thats why I am sticking on timer